# Update the value in a component using another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

Inside of my Parent I have 3 Components, NavigationBar (that displays the number of cart items), ViewCart (Side bar that displays the cart item list), and the CartButton (updates the cart items)

What i want is every time I add a new cart item using the CartButton component, I need to update number of cart items  inside NavigationBar and the list of cart items in ViewCart. Here's what I've tried so far, this is the simplified version of my code:

**NavigationBar:**

```
<script setup> 
    const emit = defineEmits(["products-available", "cart-items"]);
    watch(props.cartItems, (newValue) => {
          console.log('cart items updated');
          console.log(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"));
    });
</script>


<template>
    <button
            @click="viewCart()">
            View Cart ({{ cartItems.length }})
          </button>

</template>
```

**CartButton:**

```
<script setup> 
    const cartItems = reactive(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || []);
    const emit = defineEmits(["cart-items"]);

    watch(cartItems, 
    (newValue) => {
          localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(newValue));
          console.log('new value!');
          console.log(newValue);
          emit("cart-items", JSON.stringify(newValue));
    });

</script>

<template>
    <button id="add-to-cart" @click.prevent="addToCart">
        Add to Cart
      </button>

</template>
```

**ViewCart:**

```
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
            cartItems: {
                   required: true,
              }
    });

</setup>
<template>
    <div v-for="item in cartItems" :key="item.id">
        <!— Display items here —>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Parent:**

```
<script setup> 
    let cartItems = ref(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || []);

    function receiveEmit(cartItems1) {
          console.log('Received Emit!');
          cartItems.value = cartItems1;
          console.log(cartItems);
    }


</script>


<template> 
<ViewCart :cartItems="cartItems">
    <Navbar
              :cart-items="cartItems"
              @products-available="productsAvailable"
        />

<CartButton @cart-items="receiveEmit"/>
</ViewCart>

</template>
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: In general vue3 uses [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) to manage shared global data, if you want to set data to localstorage, I recommend [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/) that its reactive.

Comment: Also pinia has persistence plugin that handles localstorage, this fits the case

Comment: I'll try to use pinia first, thank you!